# Using Architect with Django Abstract Model class

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-architect

As specified by [PyPI Architect](https://pypi.org/project/architect/), for partitioning we can use the decorator on any model class in the following way:

```
import architect

@architect.install('partition', **options)
class Model(object):
    pass
```

My model is abstract, the column to be partitioned on is present in abstract Model and I want all the child models to have the same partitioning.

```
import architect

@architect.install('partition', **options)
class Model(object):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

- Is the above structure correct way to use?
- Will all the child models implement the same partitioning automatically?
- If **yes**, is it safe to specify decorator at the abstract level (good practice)?

*Django: 2.x || Python: 3.x* ||  *MySQL: 5.x*

Comment: Someone with 1500+ Reputation, please create the tag of `python-architect` and attach to this question :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Created and added :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't used python-archtitect on abstract models myself, but looking at its source finding a comment like [this](https://github.com/maxtepkeev/architect/blob/master/architect/orms/decorators.py#L63-L71) it is at least intended to work with every kind of inheritance.

The decorator mainly adds an attribute as a descriptor to the class which provides access to all its features: `MyModel.architect`. Normally this should not interfere with any kinds of class-inheritance.